# How to save RDP credentials into a file?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, group-policy, credentials

I'm trying to use RDP and save my credentials in a file so I don't have to enter it each time I connect.

I remember doing it before and it involved changing a group policy setting. What exactly do I need to change in Group Policy within Windows 7 in the host & client machines to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the Group Policy editor (Start > Run > gpedit.msc) and navigate to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Connection Client`

For value `Do not allow passwords to be saved`, change to Disabled.

When connecting to a machine in Remote Desktop Connector, expand the Options panel and confirm that `Allow me to save credentials` is checked.

Comment: Thanks Neil - I actually found a more comprehensive solution linked on my own answer.

Answer (score 13):

Actually found a [link](http://www.perceptible.net/post/2009/02/03/How-To-Enable-Use-of-Saved-Credentials-with-Remote-Desktop-to-Almost-Fully-Authenticated-Machines.aspx) ([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20091004021911/http://www.perceptible.net/post/2009/02/03/How-To-Enable-Use-of-Saved-Credentials-with-Remote-Desktop-to-Almost-Fully-Authenticated-Machines.aspx)) that solved this problem:

1. Hit Start –> Run and type "gpedit.msc".
2. Navigate to Local Computer Policy –> Computer Configuration –> Administrative Templates –> System –> Credentials Delegation.
3. Double click the policy "Allow Delegating Default Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication".
4. Set the policy to “Enabled”.
5. Click the Show button and enter the string “TERMSRV/*” into the list. You can also be more specific here in case you don’t want to allow the use of saved credentials with all remote machines but rather just a select few.
6. Click OK twice to close the policy.  Repeat steps 3–6 for the following policies:

   1. "Allow Delegating Default Credentials"
   2. "Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication"
   3. "Allow Delegating Saved Credentials"

Comment: +1 As it is links to a very comprehensive answer. This is the kind of answer that should be redone on SuperUser. It is, after all, supposed to be a cross between a forum and a Wiki

Comment: @IanBoyd: The recommendation is to make a Community Wiki post with a link to the original content. This is especially helpful when both the original posts have gone dead.

Comment: @Guvante And now that the link **has** gone dead; the useful answer is lost forever.

Comment: Available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20091004021911/http://www.perceptible.net/post/2009/02/03/How-To-Enable-Use-of-Saved-Credentials-with-Remote-Desktop-to-Almost-Fully-Authenticated-Machines.aspx

Comment: After completing above, run Command Prompt as Administrator and Write. GPUpdate /force

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue where Windows 10 would permanently ask for a password when I try to connect to a new machine.

First, the password line in the RDP must be named:

```
password 51:b:myEncryptedPassword
```

And the pass must by encrypted. [You can use cryptRDP5 to convert it](https://github.com/jps-networks-modifiedOSS/openvpn-als-applications/tree/master/adito-application-rdp-xplatform-embedded/src/windows)

```
cryptRDP5.exe yourpassword
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I still get prompted for the password with the dialog stating that "Your credentials did not work.  Please enter new credentials.  The logon attempt failed."

My rdp file contains something like 
password 51:b:01000000d08c9d...
With the encrypted password generated using cryptRDP5.

If I enter the password in the dialog it works.

Comment: @Milind Not sure if it is your case, but the encrypted password is linked to the machine that generated it.
If you try to use the same on another one it is invalidated.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the hostname/ip and credentials as key from PowerShell using the command :

```
cmdkey /generic:<ip or hostname> /user:<username> /pass:<password>
```

For viewing your saved keys
*Note: The saved **password will not be visible** in any case.*:

```
cmdkey /list
```

For deleting a key:

```
cmdkey /delete:<hostname>
```

This works for running a RDP session from command prompt as well as the RDP client.

Hope this helps.

For more details you can visit the [Technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've converted @barfoon answer to a registry script, to allow its automated deployment... Or just saving the hassle of navigating through gpedit.msc:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]
"DisablePasswordSaving"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation]
"AllowDefaultCredentials"=dword:00000001
"AllowDefaultCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly"=dword:00000001
"ConcatenateDefaults_AllowDefault"=dword:00000001
"AllowSavedCredentials"=dword:00000001
"ConcatenateDefaults_AllowSaved"=dword:00000001
"AllowSavedCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly"=dword:00000001
"ConcatenateDefaults_AllowSavedNTLMOnly"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowDefaultCredentials]
"1"="TERMSRV/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowSavedCredentials]
"1"="TERMSRV/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowSavedCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly]
"1"="TERMSRV/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowDefaultCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly]
"1"="TERMSRV/*"
```

Just save this in a `filename.reg` file, double click it and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone asking the same question in the future.

I created a .VBS file that enters the password for the RPD connection.

It should work on Windows 7, 8, 10, 11 ....

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("PATH_TO_RPD_FILE")
WScript.Sleep 2000
objShell.SendKeys "YOUR_PASSWORD"
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Have a good one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).