# "Remember me" feature does not work when RD getaway is used

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

The "remember me" feature does not work for me when I use *RD gateway* to connect to my workstation. *Something* forces me to explicitly type the credentials every time - I need to figure out what this *something* is.

I have the following scenario: There is workstation that is behind NAT and inaccessible from outside our company network.

1. I can connect my my workstation from inside the network and Windows *does* save the credentials after changing the [Credentials Delegation Group Policy](https://superuser.com/questions/139665/windows-7-group-policy-allow-rdp-credentials-to-be-saved).

   > Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative
   >   Templates\System\Credentials Delegation\
   >
   > Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server
   >   Authentication
2. Credentials saving also *works* when I connected to my company's network via *VPN* and then connect to workstation.
3. Credential saving *does not* work when I connect to my workstation via RD gateway -- it says *"The logon attempt failed"* and forces manual credentials entering

The 3rd scenario is the one I'm interested in figuring out - the error that occurs is shown below. When I manually put the *same* (as saved) credentials it connects just fine. The credentials to access the gateway are the same as the credentials to access my workstation.

Any suggestions on what can disrupt "remember me" feature?

[image: screenshot]
[image: scenarios]

Comment: `Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication` with that bit my assumption would be that the Remember Me feature uses some form of cached auth token or similar and as you're not part of domain in the last example that token becomes invalid.

Comment: @Seth, if I got you right it means that "remember me" would never work in such setup?

Comment: If my assumption is right than yes, it wouldn't work. But it's just that: An assumption. You'd probably have to figure out how saved credentials are actually handled. But if you look at this I'm probably wrong and there might be a way: [Enable or Disable Credential Sharing for Connections Through Remote Desktop Gateway](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732614(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. On the RD Gateway computer :

**Change the default to be “This is a private computer”**

1. Backup `C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\Pages\en-US\Default.aspx`
2. Edit `C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\Pages\en-US\Default.aspx`
3. Find `bPrivateMode = false` and change the `false` to `true`

**Change the setting so that the RDP credentials will only be prompted once**

1. Backup `C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\Pages\en-US\Desktops.aspx`
2. Edit `Backup C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\Pages\en-US\Desktops.aspx`
3. Find the line `RDPstr += "";` and add the following line under it
   `RDPstr += “promptcredentialonce:i:1\n”;`

When you are finished the section of the file should look similar to this:

```
RDPstr += getUserNameProperty();
RDPstr += "";
RDPstr += "promptcredentialonce:i:1\n";
```

Source : [RDP Gateway Customisation](https://andrewseeliger.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/rdp-gateway-customisation/)

Comment: Thank you -- I have no access to gateway itself, but I will try to get in touch with responsible peoples. Any references to sources of information would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to add the source. Done.

Comment: Although my second part is written a bit differently from the linked article, the one in the article should also work.

Comment: Thanks! I've sent a link to your answer to responsible guys that can check out gateway configuration -- not sure how fast I can come back to you with result though. To the best of your knowledge, can something be not configured properly on Client (my) side in described situation (I suppose that if it works w/o gateway, then something wrong with gateway)?

Comment: Everything is possible. The above answer might (or might not) be the solution to your problem - only trying it out will tell.

Comment: Any news regarding the problem?

Comment: Not yet... Our administrators are working on it. Sadly, I can not check your suggestion myself...