# How to save credentials to RDPW file?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, azure, credentials

I'm trying to save credentials to .rdpw file. I've found a way how to save it in .rdp file described by Makusensu here https://superuser.com/a/1336155/1751493 but I had no luck saving it in .rdpw file. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the rdp file (that stores the credentials) to rdpw.

The (new) remote desktop client should fix the file up at startup and retain the RDP settings.

[Source](https://www.srdn.io/2020/05/retrieving-rdp-files-to-leverage-the-new-remote-desktop-client-for-connecting-to-windows-virtual-desktop-resources/)